# How can I move functions attached to Object to Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript

If I have

```
var a={b:2,c:3}
```

Then

```
Object.keys(a);//returns ['b','c']
```

But say I want to add it to the prototype. I can do:

```
Object.prototype.keys=function(){return Object.keys(this);}
a.keys();//returns ['b','c']
```

Now I want to take all of the functions attached to Object and add it to the prototype. Here's what I came up with:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object)
    .filter(function(e){return Object[e] && Object[e].constructor.name==="Function"})
    .forEach(function(funcName){ 
        Object.prototype[funcName]=function(){
            return Object[funcName]
               .apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));
        }
    });
```

So I get all of the functions attached to Object. Then I loop through them and attach them to the prototype.

But then if I call `a.keys()` I get the error `TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `Object.keys` with `apply()`, so really you're doing

```
Object.prototype.keys = function(){

    {b:2,c:3}.keys(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1))
    // ^^ or whatever "this" is when you call .apply(this, arguments)
}
```

That's not what you want, you just want to call `Object.keys` the regular way here, you don't want to set the `this` value, it should be `Object`, not the object passed in, so change it to

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object)
    .filter(function(e){return Object[e] && Object[e].constructor.name==="Function"})
    .forEach(function(funcName){ 
        Object.prototype[funcName]=function(){
            return Object[funcName](this);
        }
    });
```

Of course, this entire concept is a bad idea, one generally shouldn't attach new methods to native prototypes

Comment: Thank you. Your answer made me realize my mistake. I do need to use `apply`, in order to apply the other arguments to the function. So I ended up using `return Object[funcName].apply(null,[this].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)));`. My mistake was passing `this` as the context rather than as the first element in the array of arguments.

Comment: Firsly, there's no guarantee that will work with all Object methods, they do accept different arguments, and secondly, if you're going to call it like that, you should pass in the Object constructor as the "this" value, like this `return Object[funcName].apply(Object, [].concat.apply([this], arguments);`

Comment: Okay thanks. Yeah true. I should look and verify that it works for all Object methods or include a whitelist. And good suggestions passing Object as the context.

Comment: And again, this is fun to play with, but it is considered bad practice to extend native prototypes, and adding all Object methods from the constructor to the prototype of all objects is just horrible, and can cause lots of issues.

Comment: I know it is. I'm only going to use it in solo projects. I like extending the prototype but it has come back to bite me especially when I need other libraries.